# Did Rukmini ever worry about polygyny of Krishna?

Tags: krishna, marriage, varna, rukmini

Consider the [following lines](https://www.mea.gov.in/Images/attach/amb/Volume_04.pdf#page=358) in **THE RIDDLE OF RAMA AND KRISHNA** by *Babasaheb Dr. B.R. Ambedkar* regarding the marital relation of Rukmini with Krishna

> Krishna was now, for the first time, married. He married Rukmini,
> daughter of Bhishmaka, king of Vidarbha. Her father, at Jarasandha’s
> advice, was making preparations to get her married to Sishupala,
> Krishna’s cousin and king of Chedi. But Krishna carried her off on the
> day before the proposed marriage. The Bhagavata says she had fallen
> in love with Krishna and had addressed a love letter to him. This does
> not seem to be true. **For Krishna did not remain a true and faithful
> husband of Rukmini. Rukmini was gradually followed by an enormously
> vast army of co-wives till the number of Krishna’s consorts rose to
> sixteen thousand one hundred and eight**. His children numbered one lakh
> and eighty-thousand.

Ambedkar in his writing opined that Krishna did not remain as a true and faithful husband of Rukmini as he married many women after his first marriage with Rukmini. I know that this is untrue as it is allowed for Kshatriyas to marry multiple women and Rukmini also knows that. And the marriages of Krishna with 16100 women also happened under special circumstances and also he stayed with every woman individually.

In this context, did Rukmini ever worry or complained about Krishna's marriage with others? I guess that Rukmini might be well-aware that Krishna will marry other women along with her, is my guess correct? Do any scriptures explicitly mention it?

Comment: Lol, Ambedkar can never a source to rely on. He has not even a slighest of idea of  about Hindu scriptures. It's same like learning about Hindusim from Devdutta Patnaik. 